# Is the closed disk a topology?

Tags: general-topology

I am new to topology, that is, I have just read the very basic definitions. My question is if the closed disk $D^n = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \mid x \mid \leq 1 \}$ is a topological space? I dont know how to define the "collection of sets" in this case. Can I take the collection of sets as just the points, the empty set and the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$. Please help me to sort of my confusion.

Comment: The set of points $D^n$ could have different topologies defined on it.  The topology in which every individual point $x$ has an open neighborhood $\{x\}$ is called the *discrete* topology, and in this case every subset of $D^n$ is *open*.  You should probably learn about the *metric topology* on $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a "first step".

Answer (score 1):

For any subset $A\subseteq\Bbb R^n$, you can construct (induce) a topology on it by taking subsets of $A$ that are of the form $A\cap W$, where $W$ is an open set in $\Bbb R^n$.

Sets of the form $A\cap W$ are said *relatively open sets* of $A$.